# What to do with pervert customers?

Tags: work-environment, unprofessional-behavior, employees

I work in a store in a large hospital (in USA).
In the store, we all wear uniforms and we get hospital visitors and customers who also are employees of the hospital.  Majority of the perverts who stare, standing by my register with a smirk on their faces or comment inappropriate comments out loud when I pass by in the hallways when I'm on my way to grab some food from the cafeteria, are employees of this hospital.

I wear little to no makeup and completely cover-up in my uniform, as much as possible. I did curl my hair before, but now, I just leave it straight, trying to look ratty...and yet...still...

I shut down when I'm getting these leering, staring looks or comments.

What can I do to have these men stop, at the very least, leering at me?

Comment: "inappropriate comments" is not only vague, but subjective.  What is it they are saying?

Comment: The title of the question says "what to do with perverted **customers**", but the question body says "Majority of the perverts [...] **are employees** of this hospital". That's a large difference, because the options you have for reacting to sexual harassment from customers are different than those you have with coworkers. If you choose to edit the question to make it more on-topic, please also edit the title or the question body so they match.

Answer (score 5):

> Majority of the perverts who stare, standing by my register with a smirk on their faces or comment inappropriate comments out loud when I pass by in the hallways when I'm on my way to grab some food from the cafeteria, are employees of this hospital.

Take a note of the individuals' names if possible, the times that it's happening, and then report first to your boss and then (if your boss doesn't deal with it appropriately) with HR. The latter should have a policy for dealing with employees who behave inappropriately, so you will probably have more chance of getting something done about it if you can report a number of specific incidents (as oppose to reporting the general situation, which doesn't leave them much to action on.)

Comment: The problem is that the OP is dealing with harassment from _patients_ who are a lot harder to fire. I'm not sure what HR can do about that. Maybe make management hire security personal.

Comment: @Llewellyn "Majority of the perverts who stare, standing by my register with a smirk on their faces or comment inappropriate comments out loud when I pass by in the hallways when I'm on my way to grab some food from the cafeteria, **are employees of this hospital.**" Yes, some are customers, and they're harder to deal with, but since the majority are employees it surely makes sense to at least report those instances to HR and deal with them directly?

Answer (score 4):

1. Focus on legal terms of harassment.  Staring unless it's extremely forward is not very justifiable in court, perhaps they are staring off in your direction.  Make a distinction between body language and situations to understand exactly what legally quantifies as harassment and not https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0pbHOliQu0 | http://www.wikihow.com/Identify-Sexual-Harassment | https://www.eeoc.gov/laws/types/sexual_harassment.cfm and many others you can google.
2. Document specific instances and provide names, descriptions, etc... this is very important as any harassment is personal and not generic.  You don't want to label any stereotypes(gender, age, occupation, ethnicity, etc...), but call out specific people who choose to sexually harass, even if it happens to be alot at your location.
3. Report to your supervisor, and if you are not comfortable doing that report to HR over them.  You can do it anonymously, but likely best to provide who you are.  Continue to document and update on the behavior and also if there is retaliatory responses which is another form of harassment.

Often you will be encouraged to address them directly and ask them to stop as well.  This is usually your first option, but I would get your boss in sync with you there.

**Note to Down Voters**: As a victim myself I completely empathize with not liking this answer, but USA laws define parameters of "harassment" and company policies must adhere to these laws.  The USA has porn as one of the top grossing industries as well as sexuality as a primary part of large portion of sales.  There is also at least 1 case of a sentence of 1 year for rape and a hacker to 10 years which displays the gov. viewpoint.  The only course of action to "prove" sexual harassment in order to take measures against prevention lies in the voice of the individual to state "I am not comfortable with this behavior, please stop and don't do this again." If it continues after that point it can legally be "investigated" as harassment.  Innocent until proven guilty plays in this as well.

So that being said, 1) Knowing what constitutes as sexual harassment, 2) Vocalizing one is NOT ok with the behavior of the individual, 3) Documenting specific instances of harassment in order to report it are the official USA underlying approach to sexual harassment at this time.  Without the above there is likely to be more of a case for "freedom of expression" than there is for "sexual harassment".  I totally understand this sucks for the person being harassed and disagree with the morality under this, but these are the laws of the USA.  If I am being down voted for specific errors in this answer please comment below so those can be corrected for everyone's benefit, otherwise please don't down-vote because you just don't like it.

Comment: Reason for the down vote?

Comment: It's just a guess, but it could be because of point number 1. It reads very close to you are assuming that through her behaviour she could have been "asking for it" (just in case, I assume this is not your intention) . And I know of at least some women who are sick of this kind of assumptions. Also in the next part first I understood that she should just let it happen, and need to read a second time to realise you where writing something different. Again, it's a guess, and if I am wrong I hope someone corrects me.

Comment: Thanks re-reading it a few times I could see how it could come across that way even though the first sentence was "it's not your fault if someone is harassing you"  I deleted the first bullet as the second one covers the points and intent.  If there is another reason for the down vote please put that and thanks for pointing that out @DarkPurpleShadow

Comment: Problem is, I agree completely with the post.  She says people are "leering" at her.  That could be her interpretation, when maybe the person just thinks she's cute.  I mean, it really is only harassment if she has asked the person not to stare at her, but he keeps doing it.

Comment: And if you don't feel comfortable reporting it as many do not (and often for good reasons), perhaps she could ask HR to initiate hospital wide sexual harassment training. I know the incidences of harassment I had directed to me went down greatly after we started having yearly required training.  Many people don't realize they could get into trouble and even be fired for such behavior if they have never had formal training. It also gives you a better case later if you do want to complain because they knew the behavior was wrong.